# Can i pass parameters to a windows service through GPO

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-services

We have a custom windows service written in C++. This windows service runs in all the VMs in a particular domain. I have a requirement to pass certain parameters to that windows service which the service should read during startup. Is it possible to do this through GPO or some other technique should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows Service Control Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/services/service-control-manager) (SCM) is the component of Windows you interface with to manage the services database which is held under `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services`.  Typical management operations include creating, deleting, changing the config of a service, etc.

For software developers, there are a number of [SCM APIs](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/services/service-functions) for managing this database directly to perform the above type of operations or you can use Windows built-in command-line tools such as sc.exe or net.exe which call these APIs.

**Note**: Manual editing of the registry is not ideal as the SCM keeps the config in memory so I would always recommend interfacing with the SCM where possible rather than directly modifying the database.

For the case of changing the config of an existing service with `sc.exe`, see the page [Sc config](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-config). For your case, I assume you will want to configure `binpath`.  For example:

Service name: `PSEXESVC`

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PSEXESVC`

where:
ImagePath = `%SystemRoot%\PSEXESVC.exe`

To add an argument, e.g. `-arg1` to the `ImagePath`, the command is:

`sc.exe config PSEXESVC binPath= "%SystemRoot%\PSEXESVC.exe -arg1"`

**Important**, This is unquoted and potentially a security issue should the path to the binary have spaces,  therefore the following command should ideally be used:

`sc.exe config PSEXESVC binPath= ""\"%SystemRoot%\PSEXESVC.exe"\" -arg1`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My task is to read the arguments from the service (we have decided on the write part). So if we add an argument in the imagepath of the service,something like   - "C:\Program Files\MyService\ws_dctservice.exe" -arg1, we should be able to read it using SCM right ?

Comment: Well you can use `sc.exe qc [nameofservice]` to get config information from the SCM for a service. The `binary_path_name` is what you're after.  
Going directly after the registry and not using the SCM, you could simply use: `reg.exe query hklm\system\currentcontrolset\services\LanmanWorkstation /v imagepath`.  I guess the context of how you're getting it and what you're doing with it will make your decision.

Answer (score 1):

One possible mechanism is to pass the parameters via files.

If you have a network share that is accessible from all the VMs, then you could
add the file in there.

If the file needs to be local to each VM, copying it from the share
to local folder can be done via the GPO.

For information on file transfer via the GPO, see the articles:

- [Copy files on all computers using group policy](http://kunaludapi.blogspot.com/2015/08/copy-files-on-all-computers-using-group.html)
- [GPO to create subfolder and copy file](https://serverfault.com/questions/727105/gpo-to-create-subfolder-and-copy-file)

An alternative solution is to push the parameters as registry changes.

A random reference to the method is the article
[How to Add, Edit, Deploy and Import Registry Keys through GPO](http://woshub.com/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-registry-keys-using-gpo/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I was thinking along those lines. Basically, we are already using GPO to change the logon type of that service and restarting it. I was thinking if we can use GPO to directly pass arguments to the windows service and restart it, rather than pushing files through GPO and let the service read from that file. just wondering if directly passing the parameters to the service through GPO is possible.

Comment: You could also push registry changes, added to answer.